# Display divs in "〒"

Tags: html, css

I need to display the `main` part of the page to cover the rest of the screen without the header.

The `L` and `R` part should be 50% of the page width (having a possible padding), and also 100% of the `main` height (that is, the rest of the screen)

```
+-----------------------+
|         header        |
+-----------------------+
|           |           |
|     L     |    R      |  } main
|           |           |
+-----------------------+
|        footer         |
+-----------------------+
```

Here is my code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7pc8wa2/2/):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
main {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding: 10px;
    /* changeable */
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-clip: content-box;
}

main div {        
        padding: 10px;
        height: 100%;
        background-clip: inherit;
        /* changeable */
        width:30%; /* to set=50% */
        float: left;
    }
main .left {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
main .right {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<header>This is the header content.</header>
<main>
    <div class="left">50% width, 100% main height left</div>
    <div class="right">50% width, 100% main height right</div>
</main>
<footer>This is the footer content.</footer>
```

**PS.**
I need to be compatible with "IE9 +" (so `flexbox` is not compatible)

The result at the first page load should be like in the following image:

[image]

Comment: What if the content is bigger than the screen?

Comment: I would like to explain first, then downvote, not vicecversa

Comment: Is the height of the header and footer known?

Comment: Yes, the header is 50px, the footer don't care (or not defined... anyawy is not visible without scrolling)

Comment: is it going to have scroll or is it just to adjust to the current screen size?

Comment: ideally it should scroll (I would like to add multiple "main" blocks), but till now is an option

Comment: What does "in T" mean?

Comment: I mean without the footer the interior border should represent a "T" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the not very elegant, but functional examples I got to manage is the one using the css `height: calc(100% - 50px);` function for the main element:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
main {
    background-color: green;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
main div {        
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background-clip: content-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:50%;
    float: left;
}
main .left {
    background-color: yellow;
}
main .right {
    background-color: red;    
}
```

```html
<header>This is the header content.</header>
<main>
    <div class="left">50% width, 100% main height left</div>
    <div class="right">50% width, 100% main height right</div>
</main>
<footer>This is the footer content.</footer>
```

And here is the corresponding [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1tz5h8q/6/).

The downsize, is that I

- have to use a fixed header height;
- have to use twice this header (I think to solve this using LESS file instead of the CSS one...).

Answer (score 1):

Since the height of the header is known, you can use absolute positioning

```css
header, main, footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
header {
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
}
main {
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
footer {
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>This is the header content.</header>
<main>
  <div class="left">50% width, 100% main height left</div>
  <div class="right">50% width, 100% main height right</div>
</main>
<footer>This is the footer content.</footer>
```

Comment: is not bad, just the padding seems a little strange: http://jsfiddle.net/fee60rwv/1/

Comment: @Serge It seems OK to me. How should it be?

Comment: the padding is not correct, because there is no padding in the middle (between the red and green rectangles)

Comment: I added the desired output to the OP

Comment: @Serge You need `.left, .right { box-sizing:border-box }` in order to include the padding in the width. Or remove `width: 50%` and use `.left{ right: 50% } .right { left:50% }`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fee60rwv/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is with the padding of the div's in the main container. with a little re-factoring of your css I've managed to get it to not over lap.

Here's demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h1tz5h8q/2/

```
main {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding: 1%;
}
main div {        
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background-clip: inherit;
    width:49%;
    float: left;
}
main .left {
    background-color: yellow;
}
main .right {
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: I put the padding to observe if the "columns" really fills the page in height... in your demo the columns seems to overflow the bottom of the page...

Comment: Hi serge,

I forgot to hit the save button on jsfiddle I have updated the post with the correct link: http://jsfiddle.net/h1tz5h8q/2/

Comment: I added the desired output to the OP

Answer (score 0):

### Pure CSS solution, Totally responsive, Without fixing any height (header or footer)

Here's the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/kPK5F/1/)

The only downsize, is that you have to build your HTML in a certain order. (Footer comes before the columns)

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="HeightTaker">
        <div class="Wrapper Container Inverse">
            <div>
                <div class="Footer">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="HeightTaker">
                <div class="Wrapper Content">
                    <div class="Table">
                        <div class="Column C1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="Column C2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="Column C3">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The column width may be fixed, or not.. to you're will.

P.S:
this is an old answer of mine, that have 3 columns in it, but you can change it to 2 without any problem.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However I'd prefer to keep the HTML structure as is in the OP. And the footer should not be visible (but when scrolling down).

Comment: also the footer is displaying in the top in IE9. Thanks anyway is interesting principle...

Comment: the fiddle states the browsers compatibility. IE9 isn't one of them unfortunately (because of the `transform`) - but it's still a cool technique and there is a value to show that in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Add your left and right sections to wrapper divs to handle the 50% width and padding.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
main {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding: 10px;
    /* changeable */
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-clip: content-box;
}

main .left, main .right {        
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 100%;
    background-clip: inherit;
}
main .left {
    background-color: yellow;
}
main .right {
    background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

footer {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">50% width, 100% main height left</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="right">50% width, 100% main height right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried like: http://jsfiddle.net/kPK5F/170/, but the height overflows the bottom of the screen (as we can' see the bottom padding)

Comment: Yes sorry. This is caused by the vertical padding on the float which causes it to overflow parent. I've updated the vertical padding to 0 on main .left, main .right

Comment: I added the desired output to the OP (attention at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/h1tz5h8q/3/)

Css code:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
main {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding: 2%;
}
main div {        
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background-clip: inherit;
    width:49%;
    float: left;
}
main .left {
    background-color: yellow;
}
main .right {
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: the rectangles overflows in the bottom (there is no green padding on the bottom when the page loads)

Comment: I added the desired output to the OP